# Product Images are not showing

Tags: magento2, product-images, porto-theme

Product Images are not showing after upgrade from Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1, instead, page keeps loading but nothing happens.

I am using porto theme

Comment: did you check browser's console for some error hints?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on Porto theme. When I inspected the console it was showing:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1031
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getNodeData (scripts.js:87)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at scripts.js:117
at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:70)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)
```

I have removed the following file and the problem was gone.

app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml